# Creating Nested Groupings using Linq Extension Methods

Tags: c#, linq

I am building an application that has a diary feature, and within that object there are a list of appointments. For display purposes I have a requirement to create a nested groupings in the following format

```
Heading 1

 Sub-heading 1
   Data row 1
   Data row 2

Sub-heading 2
  Data row 1
  Data row 2

Heading 2
 Sub-heading 1
  Data row 1
  Data row 2
```

where heading is the office that the appointment is in, and the sub-heading is the room that this is in. This will make more sense when looking at the following models;

```
public class Diary
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public DateTime DiaryDate {get; set; }
    List<Appointment> Appointments {get; set;}
}

public class Appointment
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int DiaryId {get; set;}
    public DateTime StartTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime EndTime {get; set; }
    public string Attendees {get; set; }
    public Office Office {get; set; }
    public Room Room {get; set; }
}
```

`Office` is an enum with office locations in, as is `Room` with rooms in it.

Currently I have solved this problem using this code:

```
Appointments.GroupBy(k => k.Office, k => k)
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Key,
                          k => k.ToList().GroupBy(sk => sk.Room)
                                         .ToDictionary(mk => mk.Key, mk => mk.ToList()));
```

I am writing the diary to a view model where the appointments is of type

```
public Dictionary<Office, Dictionary<Room, List<Appointment>>> Appointments { get; set; }
```

Essentially, my long group by statement is grouping the the data by `Office` and then using the `resultSelector` overload to project the original object. Then, I am turning that `IGrouping` result into a `Dictionary`, where the key is office and value is list of type `Appointment`. From that I am then grouping each list of type `Appointment` by `Room`, creating a dictionary within a dictionary, which produces the type `Dictionary` with Key `Office`, and then dictionary with key `Room` and list of `Appointment` as the value to each key.

This code produces the desired result, but I think it is difficult to read, more difficult to understand in the view when looping and probably quite inefficient.

Can somebody offer some advice as how I can simply the way I achieve my desired result?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. I think it's a quite good LINQ query.
You could make it a bit cleaner by introducing a helper method which would take `IEnumerable<Appointment>` and return `Dictionary<Room, Appointment>`. With that you could call it inside your `ToDictionary` call which would simplify the query a little bit. You can also skip `k=>k` in `GroupBy` call + use `a` and `g` instead of `k` which is more intuitive. `Appointments.GroupBy(a => a.Office).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => GroupByRoom(g));`
  But I don't think it's worth doing. The query is fine as is, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with @MarcinJuraszek Actually it's quite easy to read and understand, and also efficient. The only redundant is `k => k` in the first `GroupBy` and `ToList` before the second.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually building up a lookup, a dictionary with multiple values per key. Just use that.

Your query simply becomes:

```
var query = appointments.OrderBy(a => a.Office).ThenBy(a => a.Room)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Office)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToLookup(a => a.Room));
```